# Allow specific users to access my Android application on Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing an Android Personal App which I want to make this app to visible only for specific people.

1. Is there any way to provide access through Play Store login ID?
2. Is there any way to provide access through Machine ID?

After a lot of searching I got an idea for 1st requirement Private Channel may be preferable. But I'm not getting this:

> To enable the private channel feature, administrators and developers must use Google apps for an education, business, or government domain.

My app doesn't belong to any of the three categories(education, business, or government domain). Anybody, please share your ideas regarding my requirement. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why not just send them the apk file? Or put your apk file in a server where those ALLOW SPECIFIC users can login and download it.

Comment: Probably because he easily wants to push updates to them

Comment: Thanx for quick rply @LazyNinja.Yes but my requirement is, those specific users need to download app from playstore.

Comment: @DominicBartl he can put that in the application.

Comment: @SHAIKAFEEZA could you explain why it has to be from playstore?

Comment: Simply I want to start my playstore developer registration with this app.@LazyNinja @Dominic Bartl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Alpha and Beta testing feature in the PlayStore.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

> A production APK is not required to publish an alpha- or beta-test app

Answer (score 0):

You can create a google+ group and only release that app to members of that group.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Comment: thanq @Pork 'n' Bunny